# How do I return an object with a List element from a JAX-WS @WebMethod?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-ws

I have a custom Java object that I'm trying to return as a response to a JAX-WS @WebMethod. The object is:

```
public class SOAResponse {

    public String status;
    public String statusDescription;
    public List<String> responseList;

}
```

I'm having a problem with the

> public List responseList;

element.

I'm running a JBoss 7.1 server.

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What is your approach, WSDL-First or Java-First?

Comment: I'm using the Java-First approach

Comment: And what is the actual problem you got with: public List responseList;?